# How do I publicly declare the keys to an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, interface, nsdictionary

I have defined a dictionary that I would like to pass around to various other objects.  When they receive this dictionary, they need to know how it is defined so they can unpack it to get its values.  I've been using #define's in my public header to define the keys. That way, I get edit-time compiler checking to ensure I don't use a bum key.  But is there some other, more standard way to declare the interface to a defined dictionary so that other objects will get compile errors if they try to use undefined keys?

Comment: Well, there's always `#define KEY_1 @"ThisIsAKey"`.

Comment: There's no way for the _compiler_ to know what keys will be in the dictionary at _runtime_. If you really need that level of checking, you'll have to create a custom object with properties to take the place of the dictionary, which is probably not worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better than `#define` is to use constant `NSString`s. In your header:

```
extern NSString * const MyDictionaryFribbleKey;
```

(That's a constant pointer to an `NSString`.) And in your implementation:

```
NSString * const MyDictonaryFribbleKey = @"theFribble";
```

This is how the frameworks export constant strings. This won't stop the use of invalid keys, nothing will really do that (it's C, you can bypass anything), but it raises the bar higher.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a dictionary why not use an object?

The example below shows that there really isn't much extra work involved. Plus you gain the advantages of actually using objects.

**Object Set up**

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myString;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat myFloat;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myString = _myString;
@synthesize myFloat  = _myFloat;

@end
```

#### Object use

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];

// Set 
myClass.myString = @"aa";
myClass.myFloat  = 12.0f;

// Get
NSString *myString = myClass.myString
CGFloat   myFloat  = myClass.myFloat;
```

---

#### NSDictionary Set up

**.h**

```
extern NSString * const MYClassKeyMyString;
extern NSString * const MYClassKeyMyFloat;
```

**.m**

```
NSString * const MYClassKeyMyString = @"MYClassKeyMyString";
NSString * const MYClassKeyMyFloat  = @"MYClassKeyMyFloat";
```

#### NSDictionary use

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set
[myDict setObject:@"aa" forKey:MYClassKeyMyString];
[myDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12.0f] forKey:MYClassKeyMyFloat];

// Get
NSString *myString = [myDict objectForKey:MYClassKeyMyString];
CGFloat   myFloat  = [[myDict objectForKey:MYClassKeyMyFloat] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty standard way. You can also enumerate the keys of a dictionary using the -enumerateKeys method.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I've got it licked already.  Thought there might be a more elegant solution.